# Remove rows where one row offsets the next using accounting rules

Tags: sql

I have a view of materials data which contains what was purchased and reversals of some of the purchases.  I need a query that removes records that have reversals of purchase transactions.  NOTE: The view does not have a primary key.

[image: Example of data]

In the example I need to remove the first two rows as the second row offsets the first row because it reverses the purchase, but I need to keep the third row. Any ideas?

Here is the SQL for the view:

```
SELECT   LEFT(mi.Plnt, 3) AS SBUID ,
         oth.EQUIP AS PROJECTID ,
         ms.Req_No AS GI ,
         ms.Req_Item AS GI_LINE ,
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [Doc_Date], 100) + ' 12:00 AM' AS DOC_DATE ,
         mi.[SLoc] AS SLOC ,
         [Material] AS MATERIAL ,
         mi.[Description] AS MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION ,
         [Qty] AS QUANTITY ,
         mi.[UoM] AS UOM ,
         CASE WHEN mi.Mvt IN ( '101', '103', '105', '123', '261' ) THEN
                  mi.Amount
              ELSE mi.Amount * -1
         END AS Cost ,
         mi.Amount AS EXT_ORG_COST ,
         mi.PO AS [PO] ,
         mi.Batch ,
         mi.Vendor AS VENDOR ,
         mi.VendorName AS VENDOR_NAME ,
         at.AC_Group AS AC_TYPE ,
         [Mvt] AS MVT
FROM     [dbo].[MatIssued] mi
         INNER JOIN dbo.OrderTableHistory oth ON oth.SUB_ORDER = mi.SubOrder
         INNER JOIN dbo.Aircraft_Information2 ai ON ai.Equip = oth.EQUIP
         INNER JOIN dbo.RFC_AcftTypeList at ON at.ID = ai.AC_TypeID
         LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MatStatus ms ON ms.MPN = mi.Material
                                             AND ms.SubOrder = mi.SubOrder
WHERE    mi.Plnt IN ( '9131', '9132' )
         AND mi.Mvt IN ( '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', '106', '122', '123' ,
                         '261' ,'262' )
         AND mi.Doc_Date >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
ORDER BY mi.PO ,
         mi.Batch ,
         PROJECTID ,
         mi.Mvt;
```

Comment: Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

Some assumptions, based on your screenshot:

- Reversals have same DOC_DATE as purchases
- Reversals have same Batch as purchases

If the above assumptions are correct, try something like this:

```sql
DELETE FROM t
FROM MyTable t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM MyTable t2
    WHERE    
    -- Join to outer table
        t2.SLOC = t.SLOC
    AND t2.MATERIAL = t.MATERIAL
    AND t2.QUANTITY = t.QUANTITY
    AND t2.PO = t.PO
    AND t2.Batch = t.Batch
    AND t2.VENDOR = t.VENDOR
    GROUP BY SLOC, MATERIAL, QUANTITY, PO, Batch, VENDOR
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2                 -- There are 2 matching rows
    AND -MIN(QUANTITY) = MAX(QUANTITY)  -- Minimum quantity negates Maximum quantity
    AND MIN(COST) + MAX(COST) = 0       -- Costs cancel each other out
    AND MIN(CASE WHEN Cost > 0 THEN DOC_DATE END) <= MIN(CASE WHEN Cost < 0 THEN DOC_DATE END) -- Purchase DOC_DATE less than or equal to reversal DOC_DATE
    AND MIN(MVT) = MAX(MVT) + 1 -- Correlate purchase and reversal movement
    AND (t.DOC_DATE = MIN(DOC_DATE) OR t.DOC_DATE = MAX(DOC_DATE))  -- Join to outer table
)
```

Comment: The DOC_DATE does not have to be the same, unfortunately. I could not show the entire data set as the image gets quite small.  There is another column that indicates that it is a reversal (the data comes from SAP and it does not use negative numbers). So the DOC_DATE can be different and MVT column will be different.

Comment: @MikeDonner, please describe data in MVT column

Comment: The MVT column indicates whether the record is a purchase or a reversal.  The column values for purchase are odd (101, 103, 105, etc) and even for reversal (102, 104, 106, etc).  They are set up in pairs so a 101 purchase could have a 102 reversal. Not all purchases have reversals but all reversals have a corresponding purchase.

Comment: I have been unable to get this to work.  I have been considering splitting the view into two view (one for purchases and the other for reversals) with the idea of merging the views where the data matches (except DOC_DATE) but the paired MVT codes do not.  Doing research and testing on that now.